# Mostrar datos no repetidos en tabla pivote

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo 3 tablas Empleado, Tienda y Empleado_Tienda (esta es una tabla pivote relacion N:M), esta tabla pivote tiene una columna llamada FechaCambio, la cual uso para guardar la fecha cuando un empleado es cambiado a otra tienda. Por ejemplo:

```
Fk_empleado FK_tienda fechaCambio
1           2          2018
1           4          2019
2           4          2019
2           4          2020
1           3          2020
```

Para saber cual es la tienda ACTUAL del empleado 1 yo uso orderBy en el modelo Tienda.php

```
public function empleado(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(empleado::class,'empleado_tienda', 'FK_idTienda','FK_idEmpleado',)
        ->withPivot('fechaCambio')->orderBy('fechaCambio','DESC');
```

y en el TiendaController

```
public function show($id)
{
    $listarTiendas = Tienda::findOrFail($id);
    $lista = $listarTiendas->empleado ;

    return $lista;
```

Necesito listar todos los empleados ACTUALES que pertenecen a una tienda, pero me muestra los registros repetidos de los empleados, por ejemplo el empleado con id=1, me muestra que el año 2018 estuvo en la tienda con id 2, en el año 2019 estuvo en la tienda 4 y asi sucesimente. Y yo solo necesito que me muestre el ultimo registro guardado que se obtendria de hacer un orderBy (fechaCambio, DESC). creo que la solucion podria ser una subconsulta donde agrupe por empleado y ordene por fechaCambio y seleccionar el ultimo registro para asi obtener la tienda actual donde labora, y luego esa subconsulta meterlo en una consulta que me liste todos los empleados, ya que necesito listar todos los empleados que pertenecen a una tienda. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? o quizas tengo que cambiar mis relaciones, mis tablas?. Espero me puedan ayuda, gracias.

Table Empleado

- idEmpleado / Nombre /...

Table Tienda

- idTienda / nombreTienda / direccion /...

Pivot Table (Empleado_Tienda)

- FK_idSTienda / FK_idEmpleado / fechaCambio

Comment: Entonces me parece que la pregunta esta mal planteda por que en prinicipio buscas una sola tienda y eso te daría aquellos empleados que pertenecen a dicha tienda, si además le colocamos un `where` obtendríamos solo los empleados de dicha tienda que ingresaron en un año X, ahora que leo debes agrupar me suena raro pues solo podrías agrupar por ejemplo si el mismo empleado registra su ingreso a la misma tienda en las mismas o diferentes fechas una y otra vez lo cual no me suena lógico, considero que para la agrupación entonces busca todas las tiendas y agrupar por empleados por el año de ingreso

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de lo que ya tienes pudieras:

- Filtrar de todas las tiendas, **la que deseas** por su `id`
- Con la propiedad que trae la tienda, ahora accedes a la relación `empleado` que considero debería ser en plural `empleados`, para este punto tendrías un listado general donde tal vez si existen reingresos **mas de un empleado estaría apareciendo N veces**
- Una forma de limitar lo anterior es si le encadenas un filtro extra con el método `whereYear` para que de este modo obtengamos solo aquellos cuya columna `fechaCambio` sea igual al año actual

Propongo

```
$tienda = Tienda::findOrFail($idTienda);
```

Posterior accedes a la relación `empleado`

```
$empleadosTienda = $tienda->empleado->whereYear('fechaCambio', now()->year);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no puedo usar whereYear('fechaCambio', 2020), ya que hay empleados q tienen mas de  2 años, es decir el ultimo registro de fechaCambio tiene 2017. Por eso necesito agrupar por empleado, ordenar por fechCambio y luego de eso listar todos los empleados

Comment: @Edu27 por favor considera editar y añadir esto que me comentas pues en prinicipio tu pregunta como esta redactada sugiere que obtengas los empleados de una tienda donde el año sea igual a uno en específico.